# Changing the behaviour of the caret position movement in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Let's assume we have the following line of code:

```
private final String |sourceCode = "int a";
```

where | is the caret position.

If pressing CTRL + RIGHT, the caret will currently go to

```
private final String sourceCode |= "int a";
```

yet I'd like it to go to

```
private final String source|Code = "int a";
```

as happens in many other IDEs. How to change that setting in intellij?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to *Settings->Editor->Smart Keys* and enable "*Use CamelHumps words*". You can also disable the option "*Honor CamelHumps words settings when selecting on double click*" in *Settings->Editor*, to mimic better the behavior of other (Eclipse?) IDE's.

Regards